# Can I programmatically add a string to the translation interface?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have used `t()` to translate a string value. To translate it from the user interface, I first need to view the page on which this string is displayed in a different language. Only then, the string is added to the translate interface.

I want to be able to translate the string before doing that. Can I programmatically add the string to the translation interface?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your question is in regard to translating a (custom) module or theme. In that case, I'm using the [Translation template extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) to get all strings of a module/theme that are used in the t() functions. For more information about using this module, look at [this discussion](https://www.drupal.org/node/220341). Though a pretty old discussion, it's still very useful.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution, add something like this to a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_flush_caches().
 *
 * Using this as a way to get certain phrases into the t() workflow, that don't
 * seem to otherwise make it. To get these items to show up in the Translate
 * interface, go to a different language and in the Drupal admin clear the
 * Drupal cache. (ie, at /admin/config/development/performance
 */
function mymodule_flush_caches() {

  t('foo');
  t('bar');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### you can write custom code for that like this function

```
//$sourse :- string for en language or default language 
//$translation :- string you want to add in other language translation
//$langcode :- language code in which you translate string


function addInManually($source, $translation, $langcode){
  $report = array(
    'skips'=>0,
    'updates'=>0,
    'deletes'=>0,
    'additions'=>0
  ); // ??
  $source = $source;
  $translation = $translation;
  $textgroup = 'default'; // field , node, default, menu ...
  $langcode = $langcode; // 'en', 'de'
  $mode = LOCALE_IMPORT_OVERWRITE; // LOCALE_IMPORT_KEEP
  $location = ''; //  'menu:menu:management:title', '/node/3', ...
  $context = '';
  _locale_import_one_string_db($report, $langcode, $context, $source, $translation, $textgroup, $location, $mode);

  // Clear locale cache.
  cache_clear_all('locale:', 'cache', TRUE);
}
```